# semi-transparent overlays using matplotlib produce gray instead of color

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I want to make a color overlay using two gray value images, each showing a single "signal peak". In order to only have the peak appear in the overlay and not the background, I created a blue color map with an alpha channel that is ramped from 0 to 1. Using `imshow()`, I expected to see transparent color, but I see a gray halo around the peak. I played around with this problem for quite a while, but I just can't figure out what I need to do to get rid of that gray halo. Any help on making the desired type of overlays would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some code that produces the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cols

n = 41

# make Gaussian signal peaks
x = np.linspace(-1,1,n)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,x)
b = 0.3
d = -0.3   # diagonal displacement
p1 = np.exp(-((xx-d)**2 + (yy-d)**2)/b**2)
p2 = np.exp(-((xx+d)**2 + (yy+d)**2)/b**2)

# make custom colormap
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (1.0, 0.3, 0.3)),
         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.5, 0.5)),
         'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))}
myBu = cols.LinearSegmentedColormap('myBu',cdict,256)

# add ramp alpha channel
myBuT = cols.LinearSegmentedColormap('myBuT',cdict,256)
myBuT._init()
alphas = np.linspace(0, 1, 256+3)
myBuT._lut[:,-1] = alphas

# plot
plt.close('all')
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(p1, cmap='copper')
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(p2, cmap=myBu)
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.imshow(p1, cmap='copper')
plt.imshow(p2, cmap=myBuT)
plt.show()
```

You see the halo around the blue dot in the rightmost image produced by the code.

Here's what I obtain:
[image: halo]

I use python 2.7.3, matplotlib 1.2.0, and I tried different GUIs (qt, wx, gtk), without any difference.

**Update:**
Moving to python 2.7.5 and matplotlib 1.3.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, it does not produce any grey halos. See attached image.

[image: Image produced by user3535588's code]

I used python 2.7.6 as shipped with WinPython, using matplotlib 1.3.1 in ipython notebook.